Is it possible to trigger a Grafana Notification Policy from a Prometheus alert?
Is it possible to trigger a Grafana Notification Policy from a Prometheus alert JUST using Labels.
Scenario...
-Grafana configured with a Notification Policy with a label (team=devops) -AKS with Prometheus configured with some alerts that have the same label (team=devops)
-The Grafana and AKS/Prom are NOT on the same environments They are on separate AKS/VMs.
Connect Grafana Data source to the AKS Prometheus, and WITHOUT EXTRA CONFIG pickup the alert when fired and trigger the notification policy because the labels match.
I want the Prometheus to be agnostic, and just raise its alerts.
I want the Grafana to agnostic and just listen for any Prometheus alerts and send email.
If a new AKS/Prom (with same alerts and labels) is connected to the Grafana, it just picks up the alert and sends email. If a new Grafana is deployed (with same policy settings), connecting it to the existing AKS/Prom will be enough to pick up alerts and trigger notification policies.
YES I know you can configure Prometheus to have Grafana as its Alert manager, BUT it seems like it would be simple to have Grafana Notification policies watch for labels from Prometheus Alerts and send notification just based on the label.
I've have the Prometheus alerts sending the same labels and some Grafana alerts, but the policies are not being triggered.
